# Dirichlets theorem on primes

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

I want to use Dirichlets theorem on primes for my diploma thesis. I want to use following form

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Then the set $\{a\cdot n+b| n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ contains infinitely prime numbers.

Does anyone knows a good book as reference?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Apostol's "Introduction to Analytic Number Theory" is a good place to start - it takes 7 chapters to get to the result.

Comment: Google "Dirichlet's Theorem on Arithmetic PDF ", and you'll get more than 74,000 entries, many of which (the first 2-3 pages, don't worry to check much after that) are very good more or less short papers on this wonderful theorem. You're going to need quite a good basis in complex analysis (very specially infinite series of some special kinds you'll see), some good abstract algebra and time to go over those papers and pick out of them parts that you want (I'm assuming you mean undergraduate thesis, right?)

Comment: G.J.O. Jameson's 'The Prime Number Theorem' (Cambridge) is also a good one and it only takes 4 chapters to get the result. Long chapters, though.

Comment: Thanks. I only want a book I can refer to. I don't want to proof the theorem by myself in my thesis. I want to use it. And I don't know if it is possible to refer to a link in the internet or a paper. So i needed a book.

Comment: I am wondering about the editing history of this question: why is it tagged linear algebra in the end? And why someone thought this was not reference-requesting?

Answer (score 2):

- [*Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/numbers/book/978-0-387-90163-3) by Apostol.
- [*The Prime Numbers and Their Distribution*](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=STML-6) by Tenenbaum and Mendès France.

Comment: See also http://math.uga.edu/~pete/4400DT.pdf by our very own [Pete L. Clark](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/299/pete-l-clark).